# JS split object with key value pairs

Tags: javascript

I' m trying to write a code which is supposed to convert the array of arrays into an array with objects with key: value pairs inside. I got stuck with the following, where everything is fine besides I'm getting the word keys instead of actual keys inside my objects.

```
var array = [["white", "goodness"], ["green", "grass"]];


var obj={};
for (var i=0; i<array.length;i++){
  for (var z=0; z < 1; z++){
obj[array[i][z]] = array[i][z+1];

  }
}


const separateObject = obj => {
  const res = [];
  const keys = Object.keys(obj);
  keys.forEach(key => {
     res.push({
     keys : obj[key]
     });
  });
  return res;
};
console.log(separateObject(obj));
```

Comment: `[key] : obj[key]` instead of `keys : obj[key]`

Comment: [Object.fromEntries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries)

Comment: @DBS `Object.fromEntries` don't return array of object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the key in the `res.push` statement to be the variable "`key`" instead of the string "`keys`".

```
res.push({
     [key] : obj[key]
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple map like:

```js
const array = [
  ["white", "goodness"],
  ["green", "grass"]
];
const result = array.map(el => {
  return { 
    [el[0]]: el[1]
  };
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score -1):

This works by mapping the array of entries to a new array with the first element of the entry being the key and the second being the value. Destructuring to `[key, value]` is a bit cleaner and verbose than `v[0]` and `v[1]`

```js
const array = [["white", "goodness"], ["green", "grass"]];

const separateObject = arr => {
  return arr.map(([key, value]) => ({ [key]: value }));
};

console.log(separateObject(array));
```

Comment: `Object.fromEntries` don't return array of object.

Comment: It could still be useful @SimoneRossaini

Comment: It doesn't seem to me that the result given by the example refers to that.